# DataBinding issue with ActionSelect

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to instantiate ActionSelect control with databinding but I am missing something as the control does not open. Here is my code. Please help:

```
var dataStore = {
        data: [
            {
              tree: "First Tree"
            },
            {
              tree: "Second Tree"
            },
            {
              tree: "Third Tree"
            }
        ]
}

var temp = new sap.ui.core.ListItem();
temp.bindProperty("text", "{tree}");
var model = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(model);
var AS = new sap.m.ActionSelect("");
AS.bindItems("/data", temp);
AS.placeAt("content");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one error in Your syntax. It should be like this.

```
temp.bindProperty("text", "tree");
```

Also You need this line, after initializing the JsonModel:

```
 model.setData(dataStore);
```

Check here for working example: http://jsbin.com/femasabowe/edit?html,css,js,console,output